# Speeding up a function: checking NA count before computing mean

Tags: r, algorithm, vectorization, apply, na

The function below calculates the mean of a vector.  However, it first checks the proportion of `NA`'s present in the vector 
and if above a given threshold, returns NA instead of the mean.

My issue is that my current implementation is rather innefficient. It takes more than 7x longer than simply running `mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE)`

I tried an alternate method using `na.omit`, but that is even slower.

Given the size of my data, executing the single `lapply` is taking over 40 minutes.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish the same task more quickly?

---

#### UPDATE -  RE: @thelatemail 's solution and @Arun's comment:

- I am executing this function over several hundred groups, each group of varying size. The sample data (originally) provided in this question was provided as a neat data frame simply for ease of creating artificial data.

#### Alternate sample data to avoid the confusion

```
# Sample Data 
# ------------
  set.seed(1)
  # slightly different sizes for each group
  N1 <- 5e3
  N2 <- N1 + as.integer(rnorm(1, 0, 100))

  # One group has only a moderate amount of NA's
  SAMP1 <- rnorm(N1)
  SAMP1[sample(N1, .25 * N1, FALSE)] <- NA  # add in NA's

  # Another group has many NA's
  SAMP2 <- rnorm(N2)
  SAMP2[sample(N2, .95 * N2, FALSE)] <- NA  # add in large number of NA's

  # put them all in a list
  SAMP.NEW <- list(SAMP1, SAMP2)

  # keep it clean
  rm(SAMP1, SAMP2)

# Execute 
# -------    
  lapply(SAMP.NEW, meanIfThresh)
```

---

#### Original Sample Data, function etc

```
# Sample Data 
# ------------
  set.seed(1)
  rows <- 20000  # actual data has more than 7M rows
  cols <-  1000  

  SAMP <- replicate(cols, rnorm(rows))
  SAMP[sample(length(SAMP), .25 * length(SAMP), FALSE)] <- NA  # add in NA's

  # Select 5 random rows, and have them be 90% NA
  tooSparse <- sample(rows, 5)
  for (r in tooSparse)
    SAMP[r, sample(cols, cols * .9, FALSE)] <- NA

# Function 
# ------------
    meanIfThresh <- function(vec, thresh=12/15) { 
      # Calculates the mean of vec, however, 
      #   if the number of non-NA values of vec is less than thresh, returns NA 

      # thresh : represents how much data must be PRSENT. 
      #          ie, if thresh is 80%, then there must be at least 


      len <- length(vec)

      if( (sum(is.na(vec)) / len) > thresh)
        return(NA_real_)
      # if the proportion of NA's is greater than the threshold, return NA
      # example:  if I'm looking at 14 days, and I have 12 NA's,
      #            my proportion is 85.7 % = (12 / 14)
      #            default thesh is  80.0 % = (12 / 15)
      #            Thus, 12 NAs in a group of 14 would be rejected


    # else, calculate the mean, removing NA's
    return(mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE))       
  }


  # Execute
  # -----------------
  apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh)

  # Compare with `mean`
  #----------------
  plain    <- apply(SAMP, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  modified <- apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh)

  # obviously different
  identical(plain, modified)
  plain[tooSparse]
  modified[tooSparse]


  microbenchmark( "meanIfThresh"   = apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh)
                , "mean (regular)" = apply(SAMP, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
                , times = 15L)

 #  With the actual data, the penalty is sevenfold
 #  Unit: seconds
 #           expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 #   meanIfThresh 1.658600 1.677472 1.690460 1.751913 2.110871    15
 # mean (regular) 1.422478 1.485320 1.503468 1.532175 1.547450    15
```

Comment: This line `SAMP[sample(SAMP, .25 * length(SAMP), FALSE)] <- NA` throws an error for me in R3.0.1 `only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Comment: Maybe `SAMP[sample(seq_along(SAMP), .25 * length(SAMP))] <- NA` instead?

Comment: thanks, that should have been `SAMP[sample(length(SAMP), .25 * length(SAMP), FALSE)] <- NA`  (corrected in the edit)

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you just replace the high NA rows' mean values afterwards like so?:

```
# changed `result <- apply(SAMP,1,mean,na.rm=TRUE)`
result <- rowMeans(SAMP, na.rm=TRUE)
NArows <- rowSums(is.na(SAMP))/ncol(SAMP) > 0.8
result[NArows] <- NA
```

---

Some benchmarking:

```
Ricardo <- function(vec, thresh=12/15) {
    len <- length(vec)
    if( (sum(is.na(vec)) / len) > thresh)
        return(NA_real_)
    return(mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE))       
}

DanielFischer <- function(vec, thresh=12/15) {

    len <- length(vec)
    nas <- is.na(vec)
    Nna <- sum(nas)
    if( (Nna / len) > thresh)
        return(NA_real_)
    return(sum(vec[!nas])/(len-Nna))
}

thelatemail <- function(mat) {
    result <- rowMeans(mat, na.rm=TRUE)
    NArows <- rowSums(is.na(mat))/ncol(mat) > 0.8
    result[NArows] <- NA
    result
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(m1 <- apply(SAMP, 1, Ricardo), 
               m2 <- apply(SAMP, 1, DanielFischer), 
               m3 <- thelatemail(SAMP), times = 5L)

Unit: milliseconds
                                expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
       m1 <- apply(SAMP, 1, Ricardo) 2923.7260 2944.2599 3066.8204 3090.8127 3105.4283     5
 m2 <- apply(SAMP, 1, DanielFischer) 2643.4883 2683.1034 2755.7032 2799.5155 3089.6015     5
                m3 <- latemail(SAMP)  337.1862  340.6339  371.6148  376.5517  383.4436     5

all.equal(m1, m2) # TRUE
all.equal(m1, m3) # TRUE
```

Comment: Exactly. @RicardoSaporta, you're calling `sum(is.na(.))` `nrow` times. You can use the vectorised `rowSums` instead. The function overhead for calling these functions will be more than the computations itself. Probably, profiling `Rprof(); modified <- apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh); Rprof(NULL); summaryRprof()` might help.

Comment: @latemail, you should change `apply(SAMP, 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)` to `rowMeans(SAMP, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for this. I should have been more explicit in my question, in that I am very specifically executing this function several hundred times, as I have several hundred groups, each of different size.  (The confusion is perhaps my fault for oversimplifying the sample data.)    However... this does motivate the idea of melting the data by group and applying your method that way.

Answer (score 1):

Is it so that you have to go twice through your vector `vec` in your function? If you can store your `NA` first, maybe it could speed up your calculations a bit:

```
meanIfThresh2 <- function(vec, thresh=12/15) { 

  len <- length(vec)
  nas <- is.na(vec)
  Nna <- sum(nas)
  if( (Nna / len) > thresh)
    return(NA_real_)

  return(sum(vec[!nas])/(len-Nna))
}
```

EDIT: I performed the similar benchmarking, to see the effect on this change:

```
> microbenchmark(  "meanIfThresh"   = apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh)
+                 , "meanIfThresh2"   = apply(SAMP, 1, meanIfThresh2)
+                 , "mean (regular)" = apply(SAMP, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
+                 , times = 15L)
Unit: seconds
           expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
   meanIfThresh 2.009858 2.156104 2.158372 2.166092 2.192493    15
  meanIfThresh2 1.825470 1.828273 1.829424 1.834407 1.872028    15
 mean (regular) 1.868568 1.882526 1.889852 1.893564 1.907495    15
```

Comment: You should do the same benchmarking. I don't think this'll change anything. @thelatemail has got it right imho.

Comment: Good point, I added the benchmark to my post - and it seems that storing the `NA` brings some speed. At least it seems to be equally fast as the regular mean function.

Comment: I should've said, it wouldn't change much. Check the edit in latemail's answer.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion using `rowMeans` made a huge change! But before that, I thought the solution had to be slower, as it performed the regular mean first and afterwards again an `is.na` step. I haven't known that `rowMeans` is so much faster...

Comment: @Daniel, this certainly helps!  It reduces the additional overhead associated with calling `mean`.